# how to add UITabBar in ViewBased application?

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I want to make UITabBar, (not UITabBarController) in my viewDidLoad of ViewController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to 'make' UITabBar in your viewDidLoad?? I am going to assume that you want to use a UITabBar without the tab bar controller...

just create an object of UITabBar, set your controller as it's delegate, add it as a subview to your controller's view, implement the tab bar delegate methods.. and you are doen..
of course you'll have to specify how many tabs it should have, their titles, images etc just like you do with a tab bar controller...

Comment: @lukya, but how should I "init" tabBar, initWithFrame, or else?

Comment: UITabBar is a UIview afterall... you can use initWithFrame but just remember it has fixed height (49 px)..

Comment: `self.tabBar = [[UITabBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.size.height - 49, self.view.bounds.size.width, 49)];    

 [self.view addSubview:self.tabBar];`

Comment: @Seega , sorry seega, but your answer was not correct, you answer without reading my question

Comment: @Lukya, I have accepted your answer, It works upto primary level of my purpose...